# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',- Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, sigabrt

This is my full error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for rect at invalid index path (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0})
```

I have this code for my numberOfRows

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if monthlyExpenses.count == 0{
        noExpenseLabel.isHidden = false
    }
    return monthlyExpenses.count
}
```

and here is the code for my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "monthlyCell", for: indexPath) as! MonthlyExpenseTableViewCell

    //var newMode2:Bool? = nil

    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 64

    let expense = monthlyExpenses[indexPath.row]

    let date = expense.modificationDate
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE d MMMM"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date! as Date).uppercased()

    for expense in monthlyExpenses {
        if expense.modificationDate?.convertToMonth() != monthDisplayed.text{
            if let expenseSorter = monthlyExpenses.index(of: expense) {
                monthlyExpenses.remove(at: expenseSorter)
            }
        }
    }
    CoreDataHelper.save()
    if indexPath.row == 0{
        newMode = true
    }
    if indexPath.row>=1{
        monthlyExpenses.sorted(by: { $0.modificationDate as! Date > $1.modificationDate as! Date})
      let previousExpensesData = monthlyExpenses[indexPath.row - 1].modificationDate
        let day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: monthlyExpenses[indexPath.row].modificationDate as! Date) // Do not add above 'date' value here, you might get some garbage value. I know the code is redundant. You can adjust that.
        let previousDay = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: monthlyExpenses[indexPath.row - 1].modificationDate! as Date)
        if day == previousDay {
            newMode = false
        } else {
            newMode = true
        }
    }


    var expenseAmountCalculating:Double = Double(expense.amount!)!
    var expenseAmountDisplayed:String = convertToMoney(expenseAmountCalculating)

    var finalDisplayed:String = expense.currencySymbol! + " " + expenseAmountDisplayed
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    cell.dateLabel.text = dateString
    cell.expenseName2.text = expense.name
    cell.expenseAmount2.text = finalDisplayed
    cell.expenseCategory2.text = expense.category
    cell.expenseCollection2.text = expense.collection
                if (expense.expense) {
                    cell.expenseAmount2.textColor = UIColor.red
                }


                else if (expense.income){
                    cell.expenseAmount2.textColor = UIColor.green
                }

                if (expense.cash) && (expense.expense){
                    cell.cashOrCredit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cash-Expense Icon")

                }
                else if (expense.cash) && (expense.income){
                    cell.cashOrCredit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cash-Income Icon")

                }
                else if (expense.credit) && (expense.income){
                    cell.cashOrCredit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Credit-Income Icon")

                }
                else if (expense.credit) && (expense.income){
                    cell.cashOrCredit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Credit-Expense Icon")

                }
    if newMode == false{
        cell.dateLabel.isHidden = true
        tableView.rowHeight = 64
        cell.expenseName2.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 60, y: 11)
        cell.expenseCategory2.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 61, y: 33)
        cell.expenseCollection2.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 108, y: 33)


    }
    else if newMode == true{
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 64

    }

return cell
```

}

I tried executing the code after CoreDataHelper.save() 
with a condition

```
if monthlyExpense.count>=1
```

but that didn't seem to do anything. Ideally for a month with no expense in it, it should print nothing and a default view which is called NoExpenseLabel, should be visible. 
Why am I getting this error.

This is a Year View Controller I have, whenever I click on a cell, it performs the code above. So if July is clicked, only expenses in July are displayed. This is why I have the monthly expenses(remove:) code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlwIn.png)

Comment: You are making a fatal mistake: **You must not change the number of data source items in `cellForRow`**.  This method is only for assigning content to UI elements. Make expensive calculations in the model or in the controller. And in `numberOfRowsInSection` return **only** the number of items in the data source array, nothing else.

Comment: Where am I changing the number of data source items?

Comment: `monthlyExpenses.remove(at:` decreases the number of data source items

Comment: I have added a picture above and a reason why I do the monthlyexpenses.remove() is there any alternate way of doing this?

Comment: Please learn to understand how the MVC (model-view-controller)  pattern works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't remove `monthlyExpenses` in `cellForRowAt indexPath`. Because when the tableView call again `cellForRowAt indexPath` the array will have less elements that you said in `numberOfRowsInSection`. You need to remove your array's elements before and then call `reloadData`.

Comment: The reason I remove monthlyExpenses, is to only display the expenses that are related to a specific month.

Comment: Yes, but not in `cellForRowAt indexPath`. Try this: Create a function that check your array and remove the elements that you don't want to show. Call it in `viewDidLoad` or where you got the data. If you need help with this functions please copy your code where you get the data. =)

Comment: All the data is received by this array
    var monthlyExpenses = [Expense]()
as it is populated by coreData

Comment: Well, after you fill the array `var monthlyExpenses = [Expense]()` you must delete the elements that you don't want to show.